# Interpretação dos gráficos de Impulso Resposta

Tags: r

Olá, pessoal, tudo bem?

Eu estou com uma dúvida na hora de interpretar gráficos das 'funções de impulso resposta'. Já li alguns livros, mas em nenhum dos que consultei é dito de forma clara quando as respostas a um impulso podem ou não ser consideradas estatisticamente significativas.  Como exemplo, coloco os dois gráficos abaixo:

[image: Plot01]

[image: Plot02]

Não queria apenas uma interpretação desses gráficos específico, mas uma explicação sobre como interpretar qualquer gráfico gerado por funções de impulso resposta. Sendo mais específico, quais são os critérios que devem ser observados para que a resposta seja estatísticamente significativa?

Se alguém puder estabelecer esses critérios ou indicar algum livro/post/slides, qualquer coisa ajuda. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Existe um SE sobre estatísticas, em inglês, que talvez possa te ajudar nesse tópico que me parece mais de estatística do que de programação. Uma questão que parece ser semelhante: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81325/significance-of-an-impulse-response-function?rq=1

Comment: Concordo, a pergunta deveria ser fechada e removida do site.

Answer (score -1):

As respostas abaixa foram dadas assumindo que y1 e y2 iguais a zero significam que a resposta **não é** significativa.

**Resposta curta:**

Os teus gráficos são de intervalos de confiança a 95% construídos através de bootstrap. Uma regra de ouro da inferência estatística é:

> Se 0 (zero) está contido em um intervalo de confiança, então o resultado não é estatisticamente significante

Como 0 está incluído nos teus intervalos de confiança, que são as linhas vermelhas tracejadas, nenhum destes intervalos é significante.

---

**Resposta longa:**

Para a teoria da inferência estatística, intervalos de confiança são equivalentes a testes de hipóteses. Ocorre que testes de hipóteses te dão uma resposta binária: ou a hipótese nula foi rejeitada, ou a hipótese nula não foi rejeitada.

Por outro lado, intervalos de confiança te dão um intervalo no qual o parâmetro real da população pode estar. Note, nas figuras, que 0 (zero) está contido em todos os intervalos. Portanto, 0 é um resultado possível para a variável resposta. Portanto, não podemos rejeitar a hipótese nula nestes casos.

---

Referências:

1) Bussab, W. de O. e Morettin, P. A. (2013). Estatística Básica. Editora Saraiva, São Paulo, 8a edição.

2) Qualquer outro livro de estatística básica que trate sobre intervalos de confiança e testes de hipóteses

Comment: Oi, Marcus, muito obrigado pela resposta. Eu entendo seu ponto, entretanto, minha dúvida persistente, por uma questão apenas. Muito dos posts e papers que leio com análise de impulso resposta, os intervalos de confiança incluem 0, mas são tomados como estatisticamente significativos. Por exemplo, http://www.capitalspectator.com/modeling-what-if-scenarios-with-impulse-response-simulations/. Em geral, ademais, as respostas saem de zero em 1, seja a estimativa pontual, sejam os intervalos de confiança.

Comment: Em nenhum momento deste link o autor utiliza a palavra "significant" no texto dele. Além disso, quando ele afirma "The result, shown in the next chart below, suggests that the 'shock' will boost the stock market by nearly 5% after three years", em relação ao segundo gráfico, ele está sendo, no mínimo, leviano (pra não dizer mentiroso). No lugar dele, eu diria que não há evidências suficientes para afirmar que o choque vai influenciar o mercado. Nos comentários [deste link](http://davegiles.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/confidence-intervals-for-impulse.html) o autor tem uma postura idêntica à minha.

Comment: Olá, Marcus, obrigado novamente. Vou passar a adotar esse critério. Abs

Comment: Então, caso a resposta tenha resolvido o teu problema, por favor aceite-a, [como sugerido pelo site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Marcus sua resposta está errada mesmo de um ponto de vista frequentista, esses são gráficos de impulso resposta de um Vetor Auto-Regressivo, você analisa os intervalos de confiança pela evolução no tempo, e não como um todo. A referencia do Bussab não tem nada a ver, e nenhum livro de estatística básica trata de VAR.

Comment: Sem contar que essa pergunta é fora do escopo do stackoverflow e deveria ser fechada/deletada.